# wordpress plugin how to make click once upvote and downvote button

Tags: wordpress, button, plugins

hi i have created a wordpress plugin which creates two post variable one for counting upvotes and second for counting downvotes.

please tell me how can i make these to click once. Here i am able to click these button after refreshing the page.

```
function display_bar_content( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        $current_views = get_post_meta($post->ID, "post_views", true);
        if ( !isset($current_views) OR empty($current_views) OR !is_numeric($current_views) ) {
            $current_views = 0;
        }
?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".upvote").click(function(){

        <?php // execute this code after pressing upvote 
            $upvote = get_post_meta($post->ID, "upvote", true);
            if(!isset($upvote) OR empty($upvote) OR !is_numeric($upvote) ) {
                $upvote = 0;
            }

            $upvote ++;
            update_post_meta($post->ID, "upvote",$upvote );
        ?>

        jQuery(".upvote").html("Upvote : <?php echo ++$upvote; ?> ");
    });


    jQuery(".downvote").click(function(){

        <?php // execute this code after pressing downvote

        $downvote = get_post_meta($post->ID, "downvote", true);

        if(!isset($downvote) OR empty($downvote) OR !is_numeric($downvote) ) {
            $downvote = 0;
        }

        $downvote ++;

        update_post_meta($post->ID, "downvote",$downvote );

        ?>

        jQuery(".downvote").html("Downvote : <?php echo ++$downvote; ?> ");

    });

});

</script>


<?php 

$upvote = get_post_meta($post->ID, "upvote", true);

if(!isset($upvote) OR empty($upvote) OR !is_numeric($upvote) ) {
    $upvote = 0;
}
$downvote = get_post_meta($post->ID, "downvote", true);

if(!isset($downvote) OR empty($downvote) OR !is_numeric($downvote) ) {
    $downvote = 0;
}

$write = '<div id="infobar"> <span class="views"> '.$current_views.'</span> 
<span class="upvote">'.$upvote.' </span> <span class="downvote"> '.$downvote.' </span>
</div>';

$content =  $content .$write ;
return $content;
}

}

add_action('the_content', 'display_bar_content' );
```

Comment: Are you tracking the user in any way? Unless you track the user, IP address, or some other characteristic, you will not be able to prevent the upvote functionality.

Comment: no cale_b , i just want that any user is able to click only once on these buttons

Comment: Then you have to track the votes by user.  Then, when you load the page, you will check if that user has voted already, and if so, not allow them to vote.

Comment: No i want to trace votes by IP addresss so anybody can vote but only once.

Comment: hi cale_b , can you please give me the code for traking user by IP address.